# WPF resize anti-aliasing artifacts on Windows Server 2003

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image-processing, png

I am resizing PNG’s in a console app using the following WPF code in .NET 4:

```
const int width = 250;
const int height = 179;

DrawingGroup group = new DrawingGroup();
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(group, BitmapScalingMode.Fant);
group.Children.Add(new ImageDrawing(source, new Rect(0, 0, width, height)));

DrawingVisual targetVisual = new DrawingVisual();
using (DrawingContext targetContext = targetVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    targetContext.DrawDrawing(group);
    targetContext.Close();

    RenderTargetBitmap target = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
    target.Render(targetVisual);
    BitmapSource resized = BitmapFrame.Create(target);
}
```

When running on Windows 7 this works exactly as expected, but when running on Windows Server 2003 I get what I think are anti-aliasing artefacts.

[This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQfUp.jpg) shows how, when displayed on a web page with a white background, the Server 2003 image has extra horizontal and vertical grey lines in the white area that should not be there.

Zooming in on one small section to try and work out what is happening [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7ljo.jpg) shows how the original PNG has a 1 pixel semi-transparent line between the transparent section (shown as chequered grey and white) and the white area.  Both resized images have the same semi-transparent line but the one under Server 2003 has some weird variations in the level of transparency.

There is a good MSDN document on the effects of anti-aliasing when resizing images in WPF (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970908.aspx) that would seem to match the symptoms I am seeing here but why would this work differently between Windows 7 and Server 2003??

I have tried to find ways to switch of anti-aliasing to test this theory using the following code but it didn’t make any difference:

```
RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(group, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```

Answer (score 1):

AA was turned off on XP and probably Win2003 because of driver support issues. This forum posts points to a few workarounds/reg hacks.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c16c611e-f7b6-45c2-9f89-b55514817b58/#1773092

Comment: Unfortunately this registry tweak has no effect

Answer (score 1):

After a week of searching I found a solution but am not quite sure why it fixes the problem.

I noticed that the image being processed started with a PixelFormat of Bgr32 but the output from RenderTargetBitmap was Pbra32.  Reading around the P part of this format is to do with how Alpha thresholds are calculated when rendering the image so figured something could be going wrong at this stage.

The solution was to convert first convert the PixelFormat to Pbra32 with the line of code below then do the resize

```
source = new FormatConvertedBitmap(source, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, source.Palette, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, WPF uses DirectX. That means the output may greatly depends on a graphics card. Try change a bit the width and height as follows:

```
new Rect(0, 0, width - 0.00001d, height - 0.00001d)
```

If it doesn't help try to update video drivers and DirectX on your Win Server 2003 machine.

Comment: This is a headless server in a data center so not sure what kind of graphics card it would have but could explain the differences. Unfortunately upgrading to latest DirectX and adjusting the width/height have made no difference